# Java Concurrency: ReadWriteLock on Variable

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am looking for a way to combine functionality from `synchronized` with functionality from `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock`.  More specifically, I would like one method to lock only if the `WriteLock` is set, but I want the lock to be on an object variable like `synchronized`.  Here are examples that will help explain:

**ReentrantReadWriteLock Example**

```
public void methodOne(String var) {
    lock.writeLock().lock;
    try {
        // Processing
    }
    finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}

public void methodTwo(String var) {
    lock.readLock().lock;
    try {
        // Processing
    }
    finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

In this example, `methodTwo` can be invoked without blocking as long as the `writeLock` on `methodOne` has not been locked.  This is good and the functionality I'm looking for, however when the `writeLock` is locked, it is locked for all cases of `var`.  Instead, I would like for it only to lock on `var` like with `synchronized`:

**Synchronized Example**

```
public void methodOne(String var) {
    synchronized(var) {
        // Processing
    }
}

public void methodTwo(String var) {
    synchronized(var) {
        // Processing
    }
}
```

Now, the methods will only block conditional on the input.  This is good and and what I'm looking for, however if there are multiple concurrent calls to `methodTwo` with the same key, they will block.  Instead, I would like this to be a "read" style lock and allow the call.

Essentially, I would like a ReadWriteLock that I can synchronize to a variable to obtain both sets of functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Essentially, I would like a ReadWriteLock that I can synchronize to a variable to obtain both sets of functionality.

First off, depending on the number different values, this might create some huge number of locks.  You might consider having some sort of classification or something so you can partition the updates to a small number instead.  For example, is there a way you can subdivide the different var values. Maybe there are various types of values?  If there is a small fixed number of values then this won't be a problem.

You are going to have to build some sort of collection of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.  Maybe use a `ConcurrentHashMap` which will store all of the locks.

```
Map<String, ReadWriteLock> lockMap =
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ReadWriteLock>():
...
public void writeProcessing(String var) {
    lock = lockMap.get(var);
    lock.writeLock().lock;
    try {
       // Processing
    } finally {
       lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

You will need to register the different values beforehand.  Or you can create them on demand.  Again, this might create some huge number of locks which may be prohibitive.

```
public void writeProcessing(String var) {
    lock = getLockForVar(var);
    ...
}

private ReadWriteLock getLockForVar(String var) {
   ReadWriteLock lock = lockMap.get(var);
    if (lock != null) {
        return lock;
    }
    // this might create an extra lock because of race conditions...
    lock = new ReadWriteLock();
    ReadWriteLock current = lockMap.putIfAbsent(var, lock);
    if (current == null) {
        return lock;
    } else {
        return current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gray.  Like everything in life and code, there is no silver bullet.  I'm going to have to determine if the performance gain from less blocking is worth the overhead of the lock object creation.

Comment: The trick to manage the upper bound on the number of blocks is to use hashCode() as your classifier.  Change the map keys from String to Integer and use modulo to constrain the size.    Integer key = ((var.hashCode() % n) + n) % n;  will give you keys between 0 and n-1.  Pre-populate your map with locks for those keys and you are good to go.  Choose the value of n to reduce the probability of lock collision to an acceptable level.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use some kind of wrapper, if feasible. So will have a unique lock for each wrapped object.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;


public abstract class ThreadSafeWrapper<T> {

  private final ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
  private final T object;

  public ThreadSafeWrapper(T object) {
    this.object = object;
  }

  public final void methodOneWriteLock(String var) {
    lock.writeLock().lock();
    try {
      doMethodOne(object, var);
    } finally {
      lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
  }

  public final void methodTwoReadLock(String var) {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
      doMethodTwo(object, var);
    } finally {
      lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
  }

  protected abstract void doMethodOne(T obj, String var);

  protected abstract void doMethodTwo(T obj, String var);

}
```

Could be used like that:

```
public class SampleWrapper {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ThreadSafeWrapper<String> wrapper = new ThreadSafeWrapper<String>("lala") {

      @Override
      protected void doMethodOne(String obj, String var) {
        System.out.println("method one: " + obj + " " + var);
      }

      @Override
      protected void doMethodTwo(String obj, String var) {
        System.out.println("method two: " + obj + " " + var);
      }
    };

    wrapper.methodOneWriteLock("foo");
    wrapper.methodTwoReadLock("bar");

  }

}
```

You could do something similar with interfaces. Its just to point you in some direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correct I think the following will help
the solution is about just don't synchronize the object when you are going to read it, and vice versa for writing.

```
public void methodOne(String var) {
    synchronized(var) {
        // Processing the writting
    }
}

public void methodTwo(String var) {
        // Processing the reading
}
```

also I let me mention about the update method for a variable(if any)
if `methodone` is going to update something as direct-modify(like `a=12`, `name="IBM"`), so we would omit the `synchronized` block, and just mark the variable as [volatile](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#vol0), but making a variable as volatile doesn't cover locking for read-modify updates (like `a++`)

**EDIT**: Okay and if you are going to both having and eating your cake, the possible thing I think may help is synchronize on something else( than actual variable, think `pthread`), and you would give some hand of a `boolean`, okay the situation would be like this

```
private volatile boolean methodOneRunning=false;
private Object readLock=new Object(),writeLock=new Object();
public void methodOne(String var) {
    synchronized(writeObject) {
        methodOneRunning=true;
        // Processing the eating
        methodOneRunning=false;
    }
}

public void methodTwo(String var) {
        if(methodOneRunning){
           synchronized(readLock){
             //having the cake
           }
        }else{
             //when thread one is not running!
        }
}
```

and this is possible that method two start to reading at time `0`
then thread one just finishes its job after method two entered at time `1`
so here thread two will go reading the variable with locking..., so this may be solved by another thread which monitors the thread one activity and signal the thread two about the exit/termination state.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In your example methodTwo won't block at all.  I still want methodTwo to block, but only if methodOne is running on "var" (this is the ReadLock functionality).  Basically, methodOne is performing multiple actions on "var" that I am trying to make atomic while causing as little blocking as possible.  I may be trying to have my cake and eat it too :)

Comment: There are race conditions with this method.  The `methodTwo` could test for `methodOneRunning` which is false, then `methodOne` could do the synchronized and the set to true and then start processing.  This would cause both methods to be processing simultaneously.

Comment: @Gray Good point, but it could be done with a 3rd. monitoring thread as I mentioned for when thread one exists just after thread two acquired the lock.

Comment: I don't see how that would work.  When it comes down do it you are going to have to do some sort of lock test unless you want the writer to spin or something gross.  There's no easy way out here.