# Avoid global modification of static object when a thread is in particulare block

Tags: java, multithreading, static, concurrentmodification

I have two class, First class(ClassServletA.java) is the HttpServlet which stores the ipaddress and access time in the HashMap, I want to back up the HashMap in DB on daily basis, So I am Scheduling the task and storing the static HashMap object in DB and then reinitialize HashMap (after storing in DB) .

Is it possible to Lock the static Object Globally  ?

```
 public class ClassServletA {
  public static  Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

   void doGet(HttpServeltRequest request , HttpServletResponse response){
    myMap.put("ipaddress", "accessTime");
   }
}
```

Second Class is the scheduler:

```
public class MyDailyTask implements Job {
  void executeMethod(){
  //Writing the map object to file or database login here
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    out.writeObject(ClassServletA.myMap);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    // Reinitialize the hashmap 
    ClassServletA.myMap=new HashMap<String,String> ();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to lock OR  avoid the modification of the ClassServletA.myMap Map object  globally within scheduling time period when the scheduler ( MyDailyTask.java) executes the executeMethod().

Comment: Here is a solution which I can think of: 1. Create a `final` class with a `boolean` flag inside and set it to `true` by default. 2. Set this flag to `false` at the starting of your `executeMethod()` and reset it at the end. 3. Check this flags' value wherever you are modifying the map and only modify it if the flag is `true`.

Comment: if the traffic to my HttpServlet is more than I will lose some of the entries in the HashMap, while scheduling the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you just want to make sure that `myMap` is not modified while performing `executeMethod` but you don't want to block access to it for other threads you could use an [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html)

```
  public class ClassServletA {
  public static final AtomicReference<Map<String,String>> myMap = new AtomicReference(new HashMap<>());

   void doGet(HttpServeltRequest request , HttpServletResponse response){
    myMap.get().put("ipaddress", "accessTime");
   }
}

public class MyDailyTask implements Job {
  void executeMethod(){
  //Writing the map object to file or database login here
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    out.writeObject(ClassServletA.myMap.getAndSet(new HashMap<>()));
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    }
}
```

In case you want to block any access to `myMap`, consider using a [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). See other SO questions about it: [Java Concurrency: ReadWriteLock on Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552173/java-concurrency-readwritelock-on-variable)

Either way, a `HashMap` is not thread safe and requires proper synchronization for concurrent access. See [Java Multithread Access Static Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487274/java-multithread-access-static-variable)